# setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) makes my app crash

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an app with buttons that trigger sound and want the buttons to be only visible when pressed. But when I add the setVisibility method it crashes my app. Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/oneeee"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And there the java part:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout background;
    ImageButton btn;
    MediaPlayer sound;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sound.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);
        btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kick);
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting invisible before declare the button, put btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); below btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting a NullPointerException.

This is because you're calling `btn.setVisibility()` before assigning a value to `btn`. So `btn` is `null`.

Common practice is to perform `setContentView(R.layout.<layout name>)` right after `super.onCreate`. 
and you're setting the visibility of `btn` BEFORE you're initializing it to reference an actual Button view.

Suggested changes:

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xxx);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Might be a new question since it isn't related to the original question. And since you found the answer here that stopped the crash, you should mark one of the answers here as correct.

Comment: And another thought. In your `onClick` method, try changing `btn` to `v` and see what that does

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` this function before `setContentView` that's why it's crashing can you please call after `setContentView` then it will not crash

i.e,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: It will still crash. because btn is still NULL

Answer (score 0):

**btn** reference to NULL instance.

Move line

```
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

after

```
 btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You invoked btn.setVisiblility before you set the layout and retrieve the id of the button. The correct way should be setting the layout first, retrieve the button id and then setVisibility of the button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);
btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kick);
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mp.start();

    }
});
}
```